# Bootstrap 4 align text left in equal columns like table

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code for making a list of links:

```
<h3>Hours</h3>
<div class="hours-display pb-2">
  <div class="mb-0"><span class="mr-2"><strong>Mon</strong></span><span class="mr-1">9:30</span><span class="mr-1">-</span><span>23:00</span><a class="ml-3" href="#">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="BusinessHours" value="0 0930 2300"></div>
  <div class="mb-0"><span class="mr-2"><strong>Tue</strong></span><span class="mr-1">9:30</span><span class="mr-1">-</span><span>23:00</span><a class="ml-3" href="#">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="BusinessHours" value="1 0930 2300"></div>
  <div class="mb-0"><span class="mr-2"><strong>Wed</strong></span><span class="mr-1">9:30</span><span class="mr-1">-</span><span>23:00</span><a class="ml-3" href="#">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="BusinessHours" value="2 0930 2300"></div>
</div>
```

And the result you can see in the image
[image]

How to correctly vertically align the columns?

Comment: Have you tried using an actual `<table>` or Bootstrap's grid system?

Comment: No, I didn't use <table>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would restructure and do something like below, where there is an outer flex div that has children that are flex-column so the information will flex vertical instead of default horizontal.

Note that the 2nd div that contains the hours needs to have divs wrapped around the hours and the accompanying spans because there are more than 1 child element. Wrapping them in divs can allow the direct child of the 2nd `d-flex` div to wrap them correctly

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Hours</h3>
<div class="d-flex hours-display pb-2">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <span class="mr-2"><strong>Mon</strong></span>
    <span class="mr-2"><strong>Tue</strong></span>
    <span class="mr-2"><strong>Wed</strong></span>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div>
      <span></span><span class="mr-1">9:30</span><span class="mr-1">-</span><span>23:00</span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span></span><span class="mr-1">9:30</span><span class="mr-1">-</span><span>23:00</span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span></span><span class="mr-1">9:30</span><span class="mr-1">-</span><span>23:00</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <a class="ml-3" href="#">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="BusinessHours" value="0 0930 2300">
    <a class="ml-3" href="#">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="BusinessHours" value="1 0930 2300">
    <a class="ml-3" href="#">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="BusinessHours" value="2 0930 2300">
  </div>
</div>
```